# Laravel except a single route from auth middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have a route group which is protected by the auth middleware, and inside of this group I want to except one route. But this route is also located in another route group. So when I try to move it out of this group, it is not working.

How can I fix this problem, and except a `UrlProfile` function from auth middleware?.. I am using Laravel 5.1

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    // some other routes ...

    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Lawyer'], function() {
        Route::get('profile/{name}', 'ProfileController@UrlProfile');
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Lawyer'], function () {

    Route::get('profile/{name}', 'ProfileController@UrlProfile');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

        ..
        ..
        ..

    )};

)};
```

Comment: I think i can try this yes, but there are soo many routes, so I dont wanna touch them, there is no code to except one single route?

Comment: btw i tried anyways, so it works but . anyway is there a no solution to except only single route?

Comment: It works in nested. Just keep the routes outside of a middleware if its not included in the middleware. let me know if its not clear still. and if it works, please accept it as answer... :)

Comment: Moving nested groups around seems a bit drastic and dangerous to me, if you have not automated tests in place that cover this.

Comment: I dont think there is a way to do it with except so far

Comment: if my answer help you, even if its not the solution, please give an upvote :)

Comment: yeah I chose it as true answer until someone gives me a better answer. thank you :)

Comment: Thank you. I will be following this thread. It will also help me if someone gives a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, This should also work.

 You can add this in your controller.

 You can insert the name of your function in the except section and it will be excluded from the middleware. [[Reference](https://vegibit.com/how-to-protect-specific-routes-with-middleware/)]

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['yourFunctionName']);
    }
```