# Custom Middleware for one method in laravel resource controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel resource controller in one of my projects. The issue is that I want to add middleware to all methods except the index method.

How can I do this? Is there any other way without having to define a separate route for each existing method?

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966569/laravel-except-a-single-route-from-auth-middleware